# How can I control more than one project via Hello swagger. for example I want to choose a double UI selection

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

as in the picture. Can I call my controller or projects here, how is this possible For .net core web api project?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13kQY.png)

Comment: Do you use Swashbuckle or Swagger-Net or something else?

Comment: yes i use swashbuckle.